# how to use $.get with aspx pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net, get

hi all i want to know is it possible to fetch content of .aspx page via `$.get` of jquery.

my aspx page may contain **css**, **javascript**, **jquery** and **asp.net controls**.

i have used it with .html page   after reading this post

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

like this

```
$.get('Default.htm', function (data) {

});
```

and it's work fine but i want to know it is possible to do it with .aspx page.

Comment: I know you can do it with HTML and PHP pages, however, if you are loading an aspx page into another aspx page, you will most likely end up with 2 <form> tags with the same names/id's inside each other and this may cause unexpected errors for the controls on each separate page e.g. I'm pretty sure the code behind from the ajax loaded page will not be accessible so those controls will be unable to perform post backs etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `$.get` to retrieve *.aspx* pages. Just remember you're only going to retrieve the client-rendered HTML for a request. You won't be retrieving ASP.NET markup or controls, just the HTML that your page outputs once it is executed.

Similarly, the CSS and JavaScript files that your *.aspx* page "contains" are actually just links to other files. You can get these too using `$.get` (I'm just not sure why you'd want to).

Comment: actually on clicking page name from navigation bar i have to change the existing page content not redirecting to that page.